# MySQLからの出力が文字化けする(シェルスクリプト利用時)

Tags: linux, mysql, centos

MySQLからの出力が、

1. 直接sqlを実行すると化けない
2. シェルスクリプトから実行すると、文字化けする

という現象に困っています。
シェルのロケールの問題かと思うのですが、
今のところ解決しておりません。
もしお知恵をお貸しいただけるなら助かります。
以下、サンプルコードと環境を記しておきます。

---

次のようなテーブルを作成し、データをINSERTしたとします。

```
CREATE TABLE sori (
       ID int NOT NULL UNIQUE, 
       name varchar(50)
);

INSERT INTO sori (ID, name) VALUES (0, '安部晋三');
```

出力用のファイルを用意します。

```
$ cat backup.sql 
use test;

SELECT * FROM sori ORDER BY ID;
```

上記のsqlを実行するシェルスクリプトです。(ユーザ名を隠してあります)

```
$ cat backup.sh 
#!/bin/sh

output_file_name=/home/***/test.data
mysql -u root -p < /home/***/backup.sql > $output_file_name
```

直接、sqlを実行すると、文字化けしません。

```
$ mysql -u root -p < backup.sql > test2.data
Enter password: 

$ cat test2.data 
ID  name
0   安部晋三
```

次に、シェルスクリプトを介して、出力します。

```
olive:~$ ./backup.sh 
Enter password: 

$ cat test.data 
ID  name
0   å®‰éƒ¨æ™‹ä¸‰
```

こんな感じです。

ロケールですが、

```
$ echo $LANG
ja_JP.utf8
```

となっております。

最後に環境です。

```
$ cat /etc/redhat-release 
CentOS Linux release 7.3.1611 (Core) 

$ rpm -qa | grep mysql
mysql-community-libs-5.6.37-2.el7.x86_64
mysql-community-devel-5.6.37-2.el7.x86_64
mysql-community-release-el7-5.noarch
php-mysql-5.4.45-13.el7.remi.x86_64
mysql-community-client-5.6.37-2.el7.x86_64
mysql-connector-odbc-5.3.9-1.el7.x86_64
mysql-community-common-5.6.37-2.el7.x86_64
mysql-community-server-5.6.37-2.el7.x86_64
```

よろしくお願いします。

Comment: 自己解決したのであればその内容を自分で回答として投稿していただけませんか。未回答としていつまでも残ってしまうので

Comment: わかりました。すみません!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

テーブル定義のカラムのcharsetがlatin1になっているような感じに見えます。

`show create table sori;` でテーブルの charset が確認できると思います。

直接SQL実行時とシェルスクリプト実行時とで実行しているユーザーは同一でしょうか。
もし異なるのであれば `$HOME/.my.cnf` に違いはないでしょうか。

あと LANG 以外の LC_* の環境変数にも影響を受けます。

Comment: その場合にシェルスクリプト経由か否かで結果が変わるのはどのような理屈なのでしょうか。そこも解説してもらえるとうれしいです。

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。確かにcharsetはlatin1になっています。しかし、同じくcharsetがlatin1でも、問題の現象が起こらないシステムもあるので、どうも腑に落ちません。そもそもcharset=latin1がどうして「シェルスクリプトを介したときだけ」悪さをするのか、よくわかりません。また、$$LC_ALLやLC_TYPEは設定されていませんでした。今日はここまでですが、更なる検証をしてご報告させていただきます。

Answer (score 0):

解決しました。
状況と行ったことを記しておきます。

--初期の状態--

```
mysql> show create table sori; 

| Table | Create Table                                                                        
| sori  | CREATE TABLE `sori` (
  `ID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  UNIQUE KEY `ID` (`ID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 |

mysql> show variables like "chara%";
+--------------------------+----------------------------+
| Variable_name            | Value                      |
+--------------------------+----------------------------+
| character_set_client     | latin1                     |
| character_set_connection | latin1                     |
| character_set_database   | latin1                     |
| character_set_filesystem | binary                     |
| character_set_results    | latin1                     |
| character_set_server     | latin1                     |
| character_set_system     | utf8                       |
| character_sets_dir       | /usr/share/mysql/charsets/ |
+--------------------------+----------------------------+
8 rows in set (0.07 sec)
```

--行ったこと--
* my.cnfの編集 (以下を追加)

```
[mysqld]
character-set-server=utf8
[client]
default-character-set=utf8
```

- データベースの変更

  mysql> ALTER DATABASE `test` default character set utf8;
- character_set_server を設定

  mysql>  set character_set_server = utf8;
- テーブルsoriを一度破棄し、同じCREATE文で作り直す
- 同じINSERT文で、データを入れ直す

--現在の状況--

```
mysql> show create table sori;
| Table | Create     Table                                                                        
| sori  | CREATE TABLE `sori` (
  `ID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  UNIQUE KEY `ID` (`ID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 |


mysql> show variables like 'character%';
+--------------------------+----------------------------+
| Variable_name            | Value                      |
+--------------------------+----------------------------+
| character_set_client     | utf8                       |
| character_set_connection | utf8                       |
| character_set_database   | utf8                       |
| character_set_filesystem | binary                     |
| character_set_results    | utf8                       |
| character_set_server     | utf8                       |
| character_set_system     | utf8                       |
| character_sets_dir       | /usr/share/mysql/charsets/ |
+--------------------------+----------------------------+
8 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

--再試行--

```
$ ./backup.sh 
Enter password: 
$ ls -l test.data 
-rw-rw-r-- 1 *** *** 23 10月 22 16:12 test.data

$ cat test.data 
ID  name
0   安部晋三
```